# Changing an icon style for a toggle button in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to change the icon used for a toggle button depending on what state isChecked is, however the only examples i can find of how to do this use an image to display the icon.

I however, have static icon styles rather than images so i am wondering how I can do this.

As a starting point if I create my toggle botton like this:

```
 <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}">                             
     <Path Style="{StaticResource Test1IconStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />                
 </ToggleButton>
```

then it displays with the ToggleButton style and the correct Icon.

So now lets say i click the button, i need to reset the 'Path' to 'Test2IconStyle' based on the isChecked value.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of toggling Style, I would suggest to have two separate Paths in your resources and based on condition you can toggle them like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Path x:Key="Test1"/>
        <Path x:Key="Test2"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Test1}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Content"
                                Value="{StaticResource Test2}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response - if i use      <Path x:Key="Test1" Style="{StaticResource Test1IconStyle}"/>
                        <Path x:Key="Test2" Style="{StaticResource Test2IconStyle}"/> then it does change the icon Fantastic!! with one slight issue the main button style is not set, see above i use a main button style and then add the icons on top of it

Comment: You can use `BasedOn="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}"` for that. I have updated the answer with that.

Comment: You my friend are a legand if i could give you more than +1 i certainly would!!

Comment: I was a little confused by the <Path x:Key="Test1"/> for a second since I'm such a WPF noob, but I eventually realized I could just put in `<[Content Control] x:Key="SomeName"  [Specific Control Attributes] />`

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the icon in the 2 states (true and false)

```
  <ToggleButton>
      <ToggleButton.Content>
          <iconPacks:BootstrapIcons Kind="Sun"/>
      </ToggleButton.Content>
      <md:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent>
          <iconPacks:BootstrapIcons Kind="Moon"/>
      </md:ToggleButtonAssist.OnContent>
  </ToggleButton>
```